# Class attribute of type list is not being encapsulated in objects

Tags: python

The following piece of code, produces below output:

```
class BasicModel: 
   example_list = []

a = BasicModel()
a.example_list.append(1)
print(a.example_list)
b = BasicModel()
b.example_list.append(2)
print(b.example_list)

Output:
[1]
[1, 2]
```

Is this normal in Python 3.8.10?

Edit:

Defining attributes on class level, thus outside of `__init__`, will cause the property to be visible to all instances of the class.

Comment: Yes, it's a class attribute. It's not an instance attribute.

Comment: `def __init__(self):self.example_list = []` Create the list as an attribute of `self` inside of `__init__()`. This creates an instance-level attribute at object initialization.  What you are currently doing is setting a class attribute which is visible to all instances.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I have learned something new in python.